# COUNT multiple records from different tables MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, count, duplicates

I have this two mysql tables

**main_date_family**

[image]

**main_date_non_family**

[image]

I want to count duplicate records from two tables like this

```
---------------------
| id_file |  c  |
---------------------
|  1      |  3  |
|  6      |  2  |
|  14     |  5  |
```

Comment: Can you please double check your expected output? Why `2` is having count `4` in the expected output?

Comment: `|  14     |  3  |` is it expected? Isn't it supposed to be `|  14     |  5  |`?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it must be 5

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `UNION ALL` to achieve the output:

```
SELECT 
 t.id_file,
 COUNT(*) AS c
FROM 
(
  SELECT id_file FROM main_date_family

  UNION ALL

  SELECT id_file FROM main_date_non_family
) AS t
GROUP BY t.id_file
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT 
t.id,
COUNT(t.id) AS c
FROM 
(
  SELECT id_file AS id FROM main_date_family 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT id_file FROM main_date_non_family
) AS t
WHERE t.id IN ( SELECT A.id_file 
        FROM main_date_family A
        INNER JOIN main_date_non_family B ON A.id_file = B.id_file
)
GROUP BY t.id
```

**Explaining the idea:**

1. Get all the common `id_file`s.
2. Now combine all the `id_file`s from those two tables. Mind it that
   this combination holds all the `id_file`s from those two tables as
   though it's a single table.
3. Now get only those `id_file`s from second step which are found in
   the first step.
4. Now the only step left is the `GROUP BY` & `COUNT`.  <sub>I guess
   you know well what's `group by`</sub>

Comment: thank you alot, but I need the records that exist in the two tables, if one record exist in one table but not in the other, I do not need it.

Comment: But your initial requirement didn't tell this. Okay I am taking time to change the query.

Comment: Thank you so much. You have rescued me.

Comment: Glad to hear that. And also practice marking answer as accepted so that others find it useful. [**How to accept answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)